# volatile Thread object and thread object comparison in java

Tags: java, multithreading, equals, volatile

I am not much familiar with volatile keyword and thread. I have a piece of code that does comparison using ==. I got suggested these objects should be compared with equals.

```
while(pollingThread == thisThread)
```

where pollingThread defined as:`private volatile PollingThread pollingThread;`

and PollingThread is `private class PollingThread extends Thread`

`thisThread` declared as `Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();`

I have performed many String comparisons using equals and I know the rules. But I was just curios if changing the `==` operator with `.equals` method cause any issue. (I dont know what issue I gonna face)

Comment: `Thread` does not override `equals`.

Comment: I think `==` is suitable here. There's just one `Thread` object per actual thread, so `equals` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as a _volatile object_. The `volatile` keyword applies to fields. Don't confuse objects, fields and references.

Comment: What if I change from == to equals.

Comment: `==` and `equals` do the same thing for `Thread`

Comment: Then I can made this change without any fear. ? @PeterLawrey

Comment: @MonsterJava it should do the same thing. Using `==` makes it clear what it is doing.

Comment: @Peter The equivalent code would be Objects.equals(a,b) though since otherwise you can get null reference exceptions.

Comment: @Voo using `==` won't produce an NPE, only equals does

Comment: @Peter Yes, so clearly `equals` and `==` are not doing the same thing - even for Thread - if one produces an exception and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

*"I have performed many String comparisons using equals and I know the rules. But I was just curios if changing the == operator with .equals method cause any issue."*

> For String

***.equals()*** : It Overrides equals method and checks String by its reference and if false then checks by character.

***"=="*** : It checks only if both compared string references are same or not.

> For Thread

***.equals and "==" both*** are same. They ultimately checks reference for both thread.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Comment: Now try what happens when pollingThread is null and then revise the claim about them being equal ;) You can use Objects.equals instead.

Comment: @Voo you are right, In case if pollingThread object can be **_null_** then @MonsterJava can go with `Objects.equal(obj1, obj2)`